# What is the official position of Christian denominations today about Wasting seed?

Tags: comparative-christianity, masturbation, sex-acts

Human sperm are known to [live for up to 74 days inside a man's body](https://www.novaivffertility.com/fertility-help/how-long-the-sperm-lives-inside-the-testicles), after which they are reabsorbed by the body. This means that, if a man releases sperm in an ejaculation, the sperm would have been reabsorbed anyway unless that man found a woman within 75 days.

There is the story of Onan, but it seems to refer to coitus interruptus (practicing some form of contraception) when a woman is available and the man's holy duty (Levirate Marriage) was to raise children with his dead brother's widow, who would inherit the property. A separate category is spilling seed when one is not dating anyone.

Please state what Christian denomination you are answering from (Catholic, Orthodox, Lutheran, etc.) and then explain (with sources) what is the current position of your Church on the matter of "wasting seed", in the following scenarios:

1. Masturbation, where someone is "single" or a wedding is not planned within 75 days
2. Using condoms during premarital sex, e.g. to prevent catching an STD (I understand this one is a bit of a tough one, since premarital sex itself may be prohibited by some denominations, but given that it does take place, there must be some opinions regarding whether health concerns or wasting seed takes precedence?)
3. Using condoms within a marriage (e.g. as a form of contraception)

NOTE: This question is NOT asking about abortion or birth control pills.

Comment: There's a way to ask questions like this https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6537/what-about-a-denomination-survey-tag  , but what @matthew said is the problem - you need to focus on one question.  You've clearly got 3 questions * 30000 Christian denominations. here.   I'd edit our all your sub-questions and I think you should get a good answer.

Comment: @GregoryMagarshak feel free to roll back the change to your question, but I think this is on-topic, not sure if it's a dupe or too broad.

Comment: I just feel like those changes removed all the details of the question. It became a much more broad question, less precise about what it's asking. Also the link to how long sperm remain in the male body is I think essential to the question of wasting seed, since one has to know how long it would last if not wasted in the first place.

Comment: Would an answer from a Jewish perspective be welcome? The "wasted seed" issue is much discussed by the rabbis, while Christian literature  usually focuses on other dimensions of the masturbation issue such as illicit pleasure/fantasy.  In any case, I'll probably wait to see the questions future form before answer.

Comment: in the meantime, there is this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_views_on_masturbation

Comment: @DanFefferman In general, no, Jewish perspectives are off-topic on this site. Judaism has its own site.

Comment: sigh... yes... but a site where Reform and secular Jews are relegated to the status of learners, which accounts for the two largest groupings of American Jews :-(